# How to search for two phrases in the same question?

Tags: support, search

There is this myth going around the internet about NASA researching a space pen to write in space at the cost of millions of dollars while the Russians just used pencils to write in space. I wanted to know if an article on the subject exists, so I searched for "NASA pen" in the search box. the results it gave were of post with either the word NASA or the word pen.

How can I force the search to search for posts only containing **both** words, or in a broader case, to search for all the words in the search query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `+nasa +pen` as described in the [search hints](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/search):

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bnasa+%2Bpen